# Inserting multiple rows in Rails for single form

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku-postgres

There are three fields in this form:

```
employee
project
project
```

The field `project` comes up twice and so I want two records created in this case.  If I put in the values:

```
employee: John Doe  
project: Project_1  
project: Project_2
```

I would like two records in the model:

```
employee: John Doe; project: Project_1  
employee: John Doe; project: Project_2
```

This is the view:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@source) do |f| %>
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :employee %>
  <%= f.text_field :employee, class: "form-control" %>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.input :project, class: "form-control" %>
  <%= f.input :project, class: "form-control" %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Here is my code for the application controller:

```
def create
@source = Source.new(source_params)
  if @source.save
    redirect_to @source, notice: 'Source was successfully created.'
  else
    render action: 'new'
  end
end
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure about the question being asked here?

Comment: @laughingpine so the form has 1 text field for the "employee" field and a 2nd and 3rd fields both of which are "project".  When I submit the form, I want two records in the database in which the "employee" value duplicated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's not necessary to create tags for sub-versions of Rails. Look at the number of followers for each and you'll see which will give you the most visibility. Also, please look through other questions and answers and try to use similar formatting of the question's text. Stack Overflow is basically an encyclopedia of programming Q&A, like a resource book, and having a consistent look and feel is good.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, you should build the model along with two projects, then use the form helper `fields_for`, which will render both project fields

*your_controller.rb*

```
class YourController
  def your_action_new
    @object = YourModel.new
    2.times{ @object.projects.build }
  end
end
```

For the view, I don't really know how `simple_form` behaves, but basically

*views/your_views/new.html.erb*

```
<!-- blabla -->
<%= f.fields_for :project do |project_f| %>
  <div class="project">
    <%= project_f.text_field(:name) %>
    <%= project_f.text_field(:description) %>
    ...
  </div>
<% end %>
```

ALso don't forget in to accept nested attributes

```
class YourModel

  has_many :projects, dependent: :destroy
  accept_nested_attributes_for :projects

end

class YourController

  def your_model_params
    params.require(:your_model).permit(blabla, projects_attributes: [:id, :name, :blabla, ...])
    end
  end
end
```